# Windows Phone App 7.5 - 8.0 migration: Resuming... screen is infinitive

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

After migrating windows phone application from 7.5 to 8.0, it starts showing "Resuming" screen infinitely after hitting windows button first and after that back button on one of the page.
Can anybody help please how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found finally the root cause, it is caused by calling WriteableBitmap.Render() on app closing. After I remove this call, everything starts to work